# Undelete a question deleted by the community bot

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I read the [FAQ about deletions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), which suggests going to Meta for undeleting a question.

Last year, I asked a [question about migrating AWS elastic beanstalk environments](https://serverfault.com/questions/1117208/what-are-the-differences-between-the-migration-options-for-elastic-beanstalk-mul). It never received an answer or any upvotes, so it was deleted by the community bot. The question is still relevant to me, because I have to do that migration now. I don't have high hopes of receiving an answer, but I would like to give it another shot. I voted to undelete it. If you agree that it makes sense to undelete, could you vote for it too?

If I learn something interesting during the migration process, I could also then add it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such case, not negative, ontopic and just deleted by roomba; I would just repost it if I were you.

The logic is that a new question will be seen in the question's feed and it will bring fresh attention to it. If we undelete it will stay under the pile of other older questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I posted the question again.